# How can I strech a cellbackground image without a certain portion like chatbubble in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in iPhone which has a chat UI similar to hangout iPhone app. For that I need to add a chat bubble like background image to each cell which is of varying height. It has a nob like edge at the end of that image, when I am increasing the height of the cell according to the text size the entire background view is changing, but I need to increase the height of the straight portion only and not the nob part. This should be similar to the chat bubble in iPhone. I am adding the backgroundview like this

```
cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"chat_cellreply.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15.0 topCapHeight:13.0] ]autorelease];
```

I am increasing the height in row height method like this..

```
if (stri.length >50)
    {

        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
   CGSize size = [stri sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220.0f, 490.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];           
            NSLog(@"%f",size.height);

    return size.height+65;
    }
    else
    {
      return 75;         
    }
```

The image looks like this.

[image]

I want to make this similar to chat bubble in iPhone app without stretching the nob part.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use two images, one with the nob and one that can be extended down. The second could actually just be a plain `UIView` of the same color.